# VueJS + Vite in preview shows a blank loading page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vite

I've created a VueJS project using Vite which has worked absolutely fine through development but when running the `build` and `preview` commands, all I see is a blank page that hangs.

I can't seem to work out why this is happening.

Here is my `vite.config.js` file:

```
// Plugins
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

// Utilities
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls,
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => ['boodil-widget'].includes(tag),
        }
      }
    }),
    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
    }),
  ],
  define: { 'process.env': {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.jsx',
      '.mjs',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx',
      '.vue',
    ],
  },
  base: './',
  server: {
    host: 'boodil-pbb.localhost',
    port: 3004
  },
  preview: {
    host: 'boodil-pbb.localhost',
    port: 3005
  }
})
```

Comment: No errors in the console or anything? Does the request ever complete? I.e., does the page actually load, but show nothing, or does the initial request never even complete?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall a new `vite` project.  Then slowly compare yours to the copy, paying special attention to the configuration files.